How prove that$ \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x \sqrt{x y}}{x^2+y^2} \mathrm{~d} y$.converges uniformly?
I am merely guessing, but when I try to write out the specific steps, I encounter difficulties, such as scaling (finding appropriate bounds).it not correct :
$\frac{\sqrt{x y}}{x^2+y^2} \leq \frac{\sqrt{x y}}{2 x y}=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x y}} \leq \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\delta y}}$
Should I change my approach and use Abel's test?Additionally, is there any particular significance to placing these three problems together? (What is he trying to tell me?)

$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x \sqrt{x y}}{x^2+y^2} \mathrm{~d} y$


(A) Uniformly convergent for $x \geq \delta>0$
(B) Not uniformly convergent for $x \geq 0$


$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x \sqrt{y}}{x^2+y^2} \mathrm{~d} y$


(A) Not uniformly convergent for $0 \leq x \leq M$
(B) Not uniformly convergent for $x \geq 0$


$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x y}}{x^2+y^2} \mathrm{~d} y$


(A) Not uniformly convergent for $x \geq 0$
(B) Uniformly convergent for $x \geq \delta>0$


You need a combination of techniques to handle these.  Proving that convergence is not uniform is typically harder than proving it is uniform, because it is not sufficient to find that any given test, e.g. Weierstrass M-test, Dirichlet test, etc. is inconclusive.
I'll work through problem 2 to illustrate. Assuming that $0 \leqslant x \leqslant M$, we have both
$$0\leqslant \frac{x\sqrt{y}}{x^2 +y^2}\leqslant \frac{M\sqrt{y}}{y^2}= My^{-3/2}, \quad 0\leqslant \frac{x\sqrt{y}}{x^2 +y^2}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\leqslant \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}= y^{-1/2}$$
Now $y \mapsto y^{-3/2}$ is integrable over $[1,\infty)$ and $y \mapsto y^{-1/2}$ is integrable over $[0,1]$. Hence,
$$\left|\frac{x\sqrt{y}}{x^2 +y^2} \right|\leqslant g(y) = \begin{cases}y^{-1/2}, & 0\leqslant y \leqslant 1\\My^{-3/2}, &y > 1\end{cases}$$
Since $g$ is integrable over $[0,\infty)$ it follows by the Weierstrass M-test that the integral in problem 2 is uniformly convergent for $0 \leqslant x \leqslant M$.
To prove non-uniform convergence for $x \geqslant 0$ we can show that the Cauchy criterion for uniform convergence is violated.  This criterion states that the improper integral is uniformly convergent if and only if for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $C > 0$ such that for all $b > a> C$ and all $x \geqslant 0$ we have
$$\left|\int_a^b\frac{x \sqrt{y}}{x^2+y^2}\, dy\right|< \epsilon$$
For any $C>0$ consider a positive integer $n$ such that $a = n > C$ and let $b= 2n$.  We then have, choosing $x = \sqrt{n} \geqslant 0$,
$$\left|\int_a^b\frac{x \sqrt{y}}{x^2+y^2}\, dy\right|=\int_n^{2n}\frac{x \sqrt{y}}{x^2+y^2 }\, dy\geqslant \frac{x\sqrt{n}}{x^2 + 4n^2}\cdot (2n-n)= \frac{xn\sqrt{n}}{x^2+4n^2}= \frac{n^2}{n+ 4n^2}$$
Since the RHS converges to $1/4$ as $n \to \infty$ there exists an integer $N>C $ such that the RHS exceeds $\epsilon = 1/8$ for all $n > N >C$  Hence, the Cauchy criterion is violated and the convergence of the integral is not uniform for all $x \geqslant 0$.
